# play multiple wav files using DirectShow at the same and record them C++

Tags: c++, audio, directshow

I would like to create a sample application in order to play multiple wav files at the same time in C++. When a file started playing, I need to record the "sound, audio" of all of the wav files playing. In other words is to mix them during playing.

I am new with DirectX and I dont know which component of DirectX I should used for this:

I just have checked this link: http://www.mycplus.com/tutorials/microsoft-direct-x-programming/directx-components/

I should use:

- DirectShow to play multiple wav files
- How about record them, which component in DirectX, should I use?

If there is a sample open source application, I would like to know as well. It would be the best with some sample source code off course.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Frist of all, `DirectShow` is not a part of `DirectX`. Instead, it is a part of core Windows SDK and components (don't be confused by "Direct-" prefix).

Windows SDK comes with a great tool: GraphEdit. It is also described on MSDN: [Using GraphEdit](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd407274%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

You can built multi-playback graph right there without actually programming and get a basic idea how things work. You will also be able to do the same in code.

Recording might be a trickier thing, and you will address this later. You will decide whether you are using compression or now, what format you prefer. For straightforward `PCM` `.WAV` you will need an additional filter, which is available as a sample from Windows SDK, or its earlier version: [WavDest Filter Sample](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd390969%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

Comment: Actually DirectShow used to be part of DirectX at the time it was introduced (with DirectX 5 if I remember correctly).